# <a> tag click event inside innerhtml in angular 6

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I want to develop a component with the following features:

1. Page content can load with `innerHTML` i.e. dynamic data.
2. When I `mouseover` the `div`, it has to show some icon to edit.
3. Clicking on the icon fires an event. I can't get click event inside  tag to work.

(this html loaded for innerhtml)

```
<div class="profile-pic">
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4023/5154094149_8c1345f634.jpg">
  <div class="edit" style="background: #7d7c7c; border: 1px solid; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="changeEditor(TEXT)">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<p [innerHTML]="content | safeHtml"></p>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you doing, precisely, what do you expect tohappen, and what happens instead? Does your question have anything to do with innerHTML, or does it have to do with `(click)="changeEditor(TEXT)"`?

Comment: Thanks for replay. i have to use dynamic html content only. because it is used for template design. could u suggest some other plugins or how to achieve in another way.it will be helpful.

Comment: You might want to try achieveing this via [Dynamic Components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Comment: You haven't done anything I asked you to do in my comment. What are you doing, precisely, what do you expect tohappen, and what happens instead? Does your question have anything to do with innerHTML, or does it have to do with (click)="changeEditor(TEXT)"?

Comment: question is,<a (click)="changeEditor(TEXT)">Click me</a>. when click it is calling function in ts file. but when load through the [innerHTML] it not calling. event is not trigged. but href is working.

Comment: Ah. That's normal. Angular templates must be compiled. That happens at build time (in AOT mode), or at application startup time (in JIT/dev mode). You'd better use another design. Even if there are plans to make what yo want more easily doable in future versions of Angular, it shouldn't be the norm, and it will require you to bundle the Angular compiler in the production bundle, which will make much heavier than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to clicks on paragraph with innerHTML and then check event.target element.