# html content not showing when using template in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am developing dynamic template creation based on following example. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44082399/7762393)
but i can't get html output. i.e) dynamic content.
ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-item',
  template: `
    <div class="product">
      <ng-container *compile="template; context: this"></ng-container>
    </div>`,
})
export class DynamicItemComponent {
        
  @Input() content: string = `<a (click)='changeEditor('TEXT')'>Click me</a>`;  
  @Input() template: string = `{{content}}`;
    
}
```

Html:

```
<product-item [content]="selectedTemplate.content"></product-item>
```

how can i get html output. i already used safethtml pipe, that is also not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML Template using ng-template directive.

```
<ng-template #anchorRef>
   <a (click)="changeEditor('TEXT')">Click me</a>
</ng-template>
```

You can pass this templateRef as input to child component using @Input decorator.

**Child Component:**

Using *ngTemplateOutlet structural directive,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello !</h1>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="name"></ng-container>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but html content is dynamic, so  cant use ng-template. my question is. when i bind html content in template it is working, but above example not working.

Comment: for dynamic HTML content, you can use [innerHTML] attribute binding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4

Comment: if i go with innerhtml, i cant get anger tag events. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447577/a-tag-click-event-inside-innerhtml-in-angular-6